# Getting dyld: Symbol not found: _AWSSignatureV4Algorithm

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services

I have updated my AWS SDK to 2.2.5 through Cocoapods and received the following error when the app is launching on the device

> dyld: Symbol not found: _AWSSignatureV4Algorithm

I am really not sure where to start to fix, according to the docs this should be handled within the SDK.

I bumped it back down to `2.2.2` and it works fine.

Any help or a point in the right direction would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you updated the service SDK to 2.2.5, but `AWSCore` is still 2.2.2. See [Update the SDK to a Newer Version](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/setup.html#id2) for  more details on how to update the SDK.

Comment: That was it! Stupid mistake, good call!  Sorry for the late response.